# Can't stop a service started with alarmManager

Tags: android, service, location, alarmmanager

I'm having problems to cancel an alarm and a service started with it.

I set the alarm in a activity:

```
public class AlarmStarter extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      Intent locationPollerIntent = new Intent(this, LocationPoller.class);     
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE, locationPollerIntent, 0);

      alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                             SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 6000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

The [LocationPoller](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) intent will start a service to obtain the location of the device.
So I use an alarmManager to repeat this search in certain frequency.

After that when I get my location on a BroadcastReceiver, I call another Activity to show the location and fire a notification.

At this time, I would like to stop searching for the location.
So I try to cancel the alarmManager.

```
public class Notifier extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm_notifier);

        findViewById(R.id.btTurnOffAlarm).
                               setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentToStop = new Intent(this, LocationPoller.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntentToStop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast 
                       (getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE, intentToStop, 0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)
                                getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntentToStop);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But this is not working, it continues to search for the location.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make the intent unique.

sth similar to:

```
locationPollerIntent.setData((Uri.parse("YOUR UNIQUE ID FOR THIS INTENT")));
```

AlarmManager will check the data field of an intent when getting back the right alarm for you.
just set a unique Uri to the data of the intent.

so when you get back your alarm, do sth like:

```
intentToStop.setData((Uri.parse("YOUR SAME UNIQUE ID FOR THIS INTENT")));
```

the alarm should be cancelled after.

Comment: Did you wipe your emulator before each test? Maybe your previous alarms are still fetching locations. And be sure each alarm is using a unique id. So if you fire the alarm 5 times, you need 5 different IDs....just a guess...

Answer (score 1):

`REQUEST_CODE` needs to be the same in both places; you do not show where that is defined in your code listings.

Also, you do not need `getApplicationContext()` here -- `this` will work just fine.

Comment: Yes, the REQUEST_CODE is the same.

I'd like to know if canceling the alarm, it should stop the service.

Because after calling alarmManager.cancel(), it continues to search for the location.

Thanks.

Comment: @blui: " I'd like to know if canceling the alarm, it should stop the service. " -- no. All cancelling the alarm will do is stop your `PendingIntent` from being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the same instance.

```
public static final Uri MYURI = Uri.parse("Some_Uri");
[...]
locationPollerIntent.setData(MyClass.MYURI);
[...]
intentToStop.setData(MyClass.MYURI);
```

If you have two different references each time you create the Intent, it won't work.

More detailed example here:

http://malubu.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/take-your-time-widgets-and-alarmmanager/

Comment: I have the same problem, I create a singleton for the intent but still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, its not about having the same instance of the Intent "locationPollerIntent" and "intentToStop" but you must have the same instance for the PendingIntent.

After stoping the AlarmManager, the service stops too.

```
    static PendingIntent instance;

public static PendingIntent getInstance(Context context) {

    if (instance == null)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationPoller.class); 
        instance = PendingIntent.getService(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    }

    return instance;
}
```