# Unable to cancel my AlarmManager service on widget

Tags: android, service, widget, alarm

I have created a widget, which consists of 2 layout. One is having only one button "Log in". When user clicked on it, activity started for sign in. On successful sign in, widget layout changes by broadcasting intent and this layout have 2 buttons and I have set an AlarmManager for repeatedly updates automatic, one button is for refresh when user click on it. the widget refreshes and new values appear on layout and the second button is for logout, and I want to cancel that AlarmManager on setOnClickListener.

**Summary: I am unable to cancel my AlarmManager service on widget, please please please help me out of this**

**Activity Code:**

```
package widget.src;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class POPWidgetActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.widget);
        //WidgetLogOut();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome to My Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Button sign_in = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_in);
        Button sign_out = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_out);

        sign_in.setOnClickListener(login);
        sign_out.setOnClickListener(logout);
    }
    View.OnClickListener login = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(POPWidgetActivity.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            WidgetLogIn();
        }
    };  
    View.OnClickListener logout = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(POPWidgetActivity.this, "Logout clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            WidgetLogOut();
        }
    };  
    private void WidgetLogOut() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AppWidget.class);
        i.setAction("log_out");
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
    private void WidgetLogIn() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AppWidget.class);
        i.setAction("log_in");
        //i.setAction("");
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

**Widget Code**

```
    package widget.src;

import java.util.Calendar;

import widget.src.POPWidgetActivity;
import widget.src.R;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider 
{
    public static String LOG_OUT = "log_out";
    public static String LOG_IN = "log_in";
    public static boolean logged_in = false;
    public AlarmManager alarmManager = null;

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();  // this line is key

        Toast.makeText(context, "onUpdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        RemoteViews views;

        //Defining Layout of the widget

        if (AppWidget.logged_in) 
        {
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

            // Logout Button

            ComponentName com_logout = new ComponentName(context,AppWidget.class);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(com_logout,Logout(context, appWidgetIds));

            // Search Button

            Intent search_intent = new Intent(context, POPWidgetActivity.class);

            PendingIntent search_pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, search_intent, 0);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.search, search_pendingIntent);

            // Refresh call

            ComponentName com_refresh = new ComponentName(context,AppWidget.class);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(com_refresh,buildUpdate(context, appWidgetIds));

            // Alarm Call

            if (alarmManager == null) 
            {

                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

                calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppWidget.class);

                intent.setData((Uri.parse("123")));

                intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

                intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 123, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 1000, pi);

                Toast.makeText(context, "SND Refresh Rate : 5 seconds",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else 
        {
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_logout);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, POPWidgetActivity.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.login, pendingIntent);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.search, pendingIntent);
        }

        Log.println(Log.INFO, "appWidgetIds ", "");

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

    }

    public RemoteViews Logout(Context ctxt, int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {

        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);

        Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, AppWidget.class);

        i.setData((Uri.parse("123")));

        i.setAction(LOG_OUT);

        i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 123, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.logout, pi);

        if (!logged_in)
            logged_in = true;

        return (updateViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onEnabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Defining Layout of the widget
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_logout);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, POPWidgetActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.login, pendingIntent);

        Log.println(Log.INFO, "appWidgetIds ", "");

        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, AppWidget.class), views);

        super.onEnabled(context);
    }

    private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context ctxt, int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {

        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);

        Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, AppWidget.class);

        i.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

        i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.planned_value,(int) (Math.random() * 6) + "");

        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, pi);

        return (updateViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {

        Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String action = intent.getAction();

        final AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        if (action != null && action.equals(LOG_OUT)) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Request for Log out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AppWidget.logged_in = false;

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent updateServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AppWidget.class);

            updateServiceIntent.setData((Uri.parse("123")));

            PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 123, updateServiceIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            // Cancel alarms
            try 
            {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);

                Toast.makeText(context, "Cancel Alarm Successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to cancel Alarm.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            onUpdate(context, manager,manager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context,AppWidget.class)));

        } else if (action != null && action.equals(LOG_IN)) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Request for Log In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AppWidget.logged_in = true;

            onUpdate(context, manager,manager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context,AppWidget.class)));

        } else {

            super.onReceive(context, intent);

        }

    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="widget.src" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <!-- <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="false" /> -->

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".POPWidgetActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Widget Rules -->

        <receiver android:name=".AppWidget" android:icon="@drawable/widget_icon">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
        </receiver>

        <!-- <service android:name=".AppWidget" /> -->
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Intent.setData(Uri uri) you have to pass the exact same instance of Uri class.

Just save the Uri's instance somewhere (when you create it), then use that same instance when you want to retrieve the AlarmManager to cancel it.

More detailed explanation here:

http://malubu.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/take-your-time-widgets-and-alarmmanager

Look for MaLuBuTestWidget.addUri()

Same here:

[Can't stop a service started with alarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605685/cant-stop-a-service-started-with-alarmmanager/11159214)